# Why is it valid to apply a predicate to a string in an xpath?

Tags: css, xpath

I couldn't find any answers by googling. A coworker mixed up css and xpath predicates and produced the following xpath:

```
$x("//*[contains(@class, 'btn'[someattr='somevalue'])]")
```

This xpath returns all elements in the document.

My best understanding is that it is apparently possible to apply predicates to strings ('btn') and that the predicate does not match the string, thus causing the second argument to "contains" to be empty. This would then match all elements because their class attributes contain at least nothing.

But why is this legal?

And is there a way to construct a predicate that would match the string value and thus make the second parameter not empty? I tried a couple things like `'btn'[text()='btn']` but got the same result as the earlier expression.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome. If you use another browser you get an error message and/or no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is legal in XPath 2.0 but not in 1.0.

In XPath 1.0, the grammar permits a predicate to be applied to any expression, but the type rules say that it's an error if the expression evaluates to anything other than a node-set. (This is a common approach in many languages, to keep the syntax orthogonal but define rules in the type system about which operators can be applied to which values).

In XPath 2.0, all values are sequences, and any sequence can be filtered by a predicate, so it makes perfect sense to filter a sequence of strings, and since a single string is itself a sequence of strings, there is no reason to prohibit that case. In fact it is useful, and I use it frequently: consider:

```
print("Found " || $n || " error" || "s"[$n gt 1])
```

Your example would fail even in XPath 2.0, however, because the lhs of the predicate `someattr='somevalue'` means `child::someattr` and you can't use an axis expression when the context item is a string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried changing the predicate to something trivially true (`'btn'[1 = 1]`) but contains() still behaves as though the search term is empty. I don't understand why that would be.

Comment: A processor that claims conformance to XPath 1.0 should report an error; once you're in the realm of bugs, asking why the bug behaves one way rather than another is rarely productive.

Comment: Ah. I made the faulty assumption that Webkit was using XPath 2.0 since it did not complain. I couldn't find any definitive source documenting which version is used but wikipedia indicates it's still using XPath 1.0.